# iOS - Ask for push notification again after updating application

Tags: ios, push-notification, unity-game-engine, urbanairship.com

I have a game running in Appstore which connects to one of our development server and now as it is live, I am not able to send push notifications. I need to move it from develpoment server to production server (Urban airship) and it gives me new Api/secret keys. If I update these keys and update my application, will it show alert popup/register to all existing device again to new server? We have around 75k users and I can't afford to loose them! Any idea whats the safest way to play!!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
The way iOS works, you don't have to worry about the Devices Tokens not registering. Devices will have two Device Tokens per install of an app, a Production Device Token and a Development Device Token, so you should see the new Production Device Token get registered to the app as soon as the user updates and opens the app the next time around. And then you'll be set!